# knockout radio button click binding not working

Tags: knockout.js

my HTML code is:

```
<div class="radio i-checks" data-bind="click: fixPriceChecked"><label> <input type="radio" value="fixedPrice" name="bidingAllowed"> <i></i> Fixed Price </label></div>
<div class="radio i-checks" data-bind="click:allowBidingChecked"><label> <input type="radio" value="allowBiding" name="bidingAllowed"> <i></i> Allow Biding</label></div>
```

my js code is:

```
self.fixPriceChecked = function () {
                alert("clicked");
                return true;
            }
```

The click data-binding is not working. Click is not listened by `fixPriceChecked` function. What I am doing wrong?

**Update:**

I updated my HTML as:

```
<div data-bind="click:fixPriceChecked">click here</div>
<div class="radio i-checks" data-bind="click:fixPriceChecked"><label> <input type="radio" value="fixedPrice" name="bidingAllowed"> <i></i> Fixed Price </label></div>
<div class="radio i-checks" data-bind="click:allowBidingChecked"><label> <input type="radio" value="allowBiding" name="bidingAllowed"> <i></i> Allow Biding</label></div>
```

Now when I click on `click here` its working fine. That means there is some issue with radio button. The click is not working ONLY with radio button.

Comment: Are you getting any console errors in browser?

Comment: no I am not getting any error

Comment: it working fine check here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26485/ .

Comment: @supercool Its not working for me. I have updated the quesiton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Html element Input is a self closing tag `<input />` you can correct that.

you code by default works fine check [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26487/)

I dont think its good idea to have a click on div as we already having `checked` option for radio buttons

*Update :* you need to use custom binding Handlers to integrate `iCheck` plugin .

**view:**

```
<div>
    <label>
        <input class="radio i-checks" type="radio" data-bind="iChecked: fixedPrice " name="1" value="fixedPrice" />Fixed Price</label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        <input class="radio i-checks" type="radio" data-bind="iChecked: allowBiding " name="1" value="allowBiding" />Allow Biding</label>
</div>
```

**viewModel:**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.iChecked = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).iCheck({
            radioClass: "iradio_square-green",
        });
        $(element).on('ifChanged', function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element)[0].checked);
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        if (value) {
            $(element).iCheck('check');
        } else {
            $(element).iCheck('uncheck');
        }
    }
};

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.fixedPrice = ko.observable(true);
    self.allowBiding = ko.observable(false);

};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

working sample with radio button checked binding **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26494/)**

just incase if you are looking for a selected value try **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26492/)**

Comment: I have copied and pasted your code as it is but its not working. I had tried checked binding before posting question.

Comment: can you try like this which is a standard way to do this http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26488/ . let me know

Comment: checked binding should match with value in html element . try forking my fiddle and show the error & let us know for any console errors

Comment: there is no error in console. Everything is just fine. `selectedVal` value is changed according to selected radio button. What next?

Comment: so that's it @IrfanWattoo . now checked binding is working as expected . you expecting anything more ?

Comment: ok I have figured it out. It was not working just because of `i-checks` class. When I remove `i-checks` class It works fine. I am using icheck plugin. and its script is  `$('.i-checks').iCheck({
                checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
                radioClass: 'iradio_square-green',
            });` Have you used icheck plugin. Why its not working?

Answer (score 0):

you need the "checked" binding ;-)

Look at the page in "Example adding radio buttons":
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html

Comment: not working. I have added this line in viewModel `self.isFixPriceChecked = ko.observable("fixedPrice");` and updated HTML to : `<div class="radio i-checks" data-bind="click: fixPriceChecked"><label> <input type="radio" data-bind="checked:isFixPriceChecked" value="fixedPrice" name="bidingAllowed"> <i></i> Fixed Price </label></div>` but no success

Comment: Do you have the Data - Bind always on the same property? You always have to refer to the same property . in which the value is written from the Value attributes . <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="cherry" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor" /> Cherry</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="almond" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor" /> Almond</div>